# Breaklink is not working when using variable instead of giving whole path

Tags: excel, line-breaks, vba

I used the below code to break my links:   
`ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:="C:\Users\admin\desktop\tool\breaklink tool.xls", Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks`

But the problem is tool will not reside in same path everytime. So i used the below code:

`toolpath = Thisworkbook.Path + "\breaklink tool.xls"
ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink Name:=toolpath, Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks`

But this is not working. It is throwing the below error:

[image]

And if i click debug and press f5 to continue, links are braking. This is totally annoying. i don't know where i did wrong.Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub BreakLinks()
    Dim arrLinks
    Dim i                As Long
    arrLinks = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
    If Not IsEmpty(arrLinks) Then
        For i = LBound(arrLinks) To UBound(arrLinks)
            If InStr(1, arrLinks(i), "\breaklink tool.xls", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then _
                        ActiveWorkbook.BreakLink arrLinks(i), xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
        Next i
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Cool... Its working.. But i couldn't understand how it is working and Why the code i used is not working? Can you please explain me?

Comment: I understood why my code is not working. With the button i used it creates a new sheet and which should be saved for my code to work!! That was the problem in my code